# Unmarshal struct в golang

Tags: json, golang, struct

Привет. Есть Reader:

```
func (r *GzipLineReader) ReadItem(item interface{}) error {
    if !r.Scanner.Scan() {
        return io.EOF
    }

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(item))
    err := json.Unmarshal(r.Scanner.Bytes(), &item)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(item))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

В качестве аргумента ему передаётся структура

```
type ThesaurusItem struct {

    Id int
    ObjectType ObjectNodeGraphType
    ThesaurusId int `json:"id"`
    Keywords []string `json:"keywords"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}
```

Сканер связан с файлом, в котором построчно записаны json`ы вида:

```
{"id":466,"type":"Книжный магазин","keywords":["книги","журналы","карты","купить книгу","книжный","книга","книги","книге","книгу","книгой","книгою","книг","книгам","книгами","книгах","журнал","журнала","журналу","журналом","журнале","журналы","журналов","журналам","журналами","журналах","карта","карты","карте","карту","картой","картою","карт","картам","картами","картах","книжный","книжного","книжному","книжным","книжном","книжная","книжной","книжную","книжною","книжное","книжные","книжных","книжными","книжн","книжна","книжно","книжны"]}
```

В консоле я имею:

> ThesaurusItem
>
> map[string]interface {}

Я не понимаю причины такого поведения. Почему interface становится map? Как достичь того состояния, в котором незаполненный интерфейс, после выполнения функции Unmarshall окажется заполненным интерфейсом с данными?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам код, который показывает, что вы делаете не так: https://play.golang.org/p/asqKup5tN0. `json.Unmarshal` и подобные ему функции ожидают указатель на значение, запакованное в пустой интерфейс. Вы же даёте ему указатель на пустой интерфейс, в котором лежит значение. Чтобы ваш код заработал, передавайте в метод `ReadItem` указатель, а в `json.Unmarshal` - просто интерфейс, который к вам пришёл:

```
func (r *GzipLineReader) ReadItem(item interface{}) error {
    // ...
    err := json.Unmarshal(r.Scanner.Bytes(), item)
    // ...
}

// ...

err := glr.ReadItem(&item)
```

---

Помимо этого, следуйте официальным гайдлайнам (`Id` должно быть `ID`) и не забывайте про gofmt (код вашей структуры плохо читаем). А чтобы распечатать тип переменной, используйте `fmt.Printf("%T", v)`.

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под `json.Unmarshal и подобные ему функции` ?

Comment: Вы не знаете, почему сделана именно такая реализация json.Unmarshal?

Comment: Что касается gofmt, то я им, разумеется, пользуюсь. Но в данном случае я скопировал структуру из кода, где были комментарии, которые я удалил здесь, на стеке, поэтому gofmt не применил. ID поправлю, спасибо.

Comment: @hedgehogues "Подобные" - почти любые функции для работы с сериализацией. Например, `encoding/xml`. И что значит "именно такая" реализация? Вы даёте указатель на объект конкретного типа - вам его заполняют; даёте указатель на пустой интерфейс - получаете значение по умолчанию. Для JSON-объектов это `map[string]interface{}`.